# How to parse xml using scrapy

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, scrapy

How to scrape the XML using scrapy.

My XML looks something like this:

```
    <rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
    <generator>NFE/5.0</generator>
    <title>"python" - Google News</title>
    <link>
    https://news.google.com/search?q=python&hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en
    </link>
    <language>en-IN</language>
    <webMaster>news-webmaster@google.com</webMaster>
    <copyright>2019 Google Inc.</copyright>
    <lastBuildDate>Thu, 07 Mar 2019 16:48:55 GMT</lastBuildDate>
    <description>Google News</description>
    <item>
    <title>
    Brown snake attacks python eating a rat - NEWS.com.au
    </title>
    </channel>
    </rss>
```

My code looks like this:

```
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.selector import Selector


response = HtmlResponse(url='https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=python&hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en')
xxs = Selector(response)
obj = xxs.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
```

I want to get the text in the title tag. But here I'm getting an empty list. Please help me out. It's important.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You are getting **forbidden** by robots.txt.
You need to change this behavior in the `settings.py` and change `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=True`to `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False`.